# iPhone not showing in Xcode / iTunes

Tags: iphone, xcode

After plugging my iPhone to Macbook Pro the phone is charging and visible in the USB section of System Report but doesn't appear in neither iTunes nor Xcode. Can someone help me fixing it ? I restarted both devices multiple times but it didn't work.

Comment: This may be a hardware issue. Did you try changing cables/testing other ports?

Comment: Yes, I did test multiple cables and ports. After reinstalling the Mac OS the problem disappeared but I know it will come again some day.